# How can I link a Grid gesture to a View Model command?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I tried so far:

```
<Grid x:Name="wordGrid" Padding="10,0,10,0">
   <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding wordGridClickedCommand}" />
   </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

In the view model:

```
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{

    public PhrasesFrameViewModel()
    {
        var wordGridClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            if (App.Timer1Running)
                ResetTimer1();
            else
                ResetTimer2();
        });
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint in the command it doesn't get reached when I tap on the grid.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` only works with [properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#Data_Bindings).

You can expose a property in your view model as:

```
private ICommand wordGridClickedCommand;
pubilc ICommand WordGridClickedCommand 
{ 
    get { return wordGridClickedCommand; } 
    set 
    { 
        wordGridClickedCommand = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and make sure to update binding path to `WordGridClickedCommand` in XAML.

**EDIT-1**

Or you can use:

```
private ICommand wordGridClickedCommand;
pubilc ICommand WordGridClickedCommand 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return wordGridClickedCommand ?? 
            (wordGridClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                if (App.Timer1Running)
                    ResetTimer1();
                else
                    ResetTimer2();
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I also just put the wordGridClickedCommand code after the return or inside the get ?  Also if not then should the wordGridClickedCommand code be inside the constructor?

Comment: You can still keep the handler code in constructor, or move it to getter. But if you move it to get - keep in mind to do a null check before setting command - something along the lines of `wordGridClickedCommand = wordGridClickedCommand ?? new Command(..`;

Comment: If you have a few minutes could you give an example of how it could be coded in the get.  Thanks

Comment: Answer updated. - hope it helps! You don't need a setter I guess.